# the ajax Request not sending Email in php

Tags: php, ajax

i am using correct `code`, still the ajax request is not `sending the email` content-- Can anyone have a look and suggest me what i can do better to get an `email`

Here is the `form` :

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <div class="element">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label>Phone </label>
        <input type="text" name="website" class="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <label>Comment</label>
        <textarea name="comment" class="text textarea" /></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="element">

        <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
        <div class="loading"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the ajax request: --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //if submit button is clicked
    $('#submit').click(function () {        

        //Get the data from all the fields
        var name = $('input[name=name]');
        var email = $('input[name=email]');
        var website = $('input[name=website]');
        var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');

        //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
        //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field
        if (name.val()=='') {
            name.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else name.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (email.val()=='') {
            email.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else email.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (comment.val()=='') {
            comment.addClass('hightlight');
            return false;
        } else comment.removeClass('hightlight');

        //organize the data properly
        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&website=' + 
        website.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());

        //disabled all the text fields
        $('.text').attr('enabled','false');

        //show the loading sign
        $('.loading').show();

        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "process.php", 

            //GET method is used
            type: "GET",

            //pass the data         
            data: data,     

            //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,

            //success
            success: function (html) {              
                //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
                if (html==1) {                  
                    //hide the form
                    $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                 

                    //show the success message
                    $('.done').fadeIn('slow');

                //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
                } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');               
            }       
        });

        //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

and `process.php` as

```
<?php

//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$website = ($_GET['website']) ?$_GET['website'] : $_POST['website'];
$comment = ($_GET['comment']) ?$_GET['comment'] : $_POST['comment'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$comment) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your comment.'; 

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail / no errors found
if (!$errors) {


//recipient
    $to = 'info@abc.com';   
    //sender
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'Comment from ' . $name; 
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone</td><td>' . $website . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Comment</td><td>' . nl2br($comment) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';

    //This one for ajax
    //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo '1';   
    }


} else {
    //display the errors message
    for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
    echo '<a href="yourdomain.com">Back</a>';
    exit;
}


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result) return 1;
    else return 0;
}



?>
```

Any help in the end ? Thankyou

Comment: How far is it getting? Does the ajax fire? Do you receive all of the form data in the PHP? Is it just the email that's not sending?

Comment: Its just an `email` is not sending, everything is works out perfectly. you may check it as `http://goo.gl/GXIu5`

Comment: What is the result of `sendmail()`, it should indicate if the message was accepted for delivery or not.

Comment: If you are running PHP on windows, you may need additional configuring to get mail to work

Comment: I am receiving full `message` as `Thank you ! We have received your message.`,. But its not sending the `email` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please browse *process.php?name=jone&email=john@example.com&website=www.blabla.com&comment=blablabla* to know if the problem is in the server side script.

Comment: I am receiving full `message` as `Thank you ! We have received your message.`,. But its not sending the `email` only

Comment: do you have smtp server set in php.ini ?

Comment: from only this script i am not getting the email, normally everything works out prpperly

Comment: Do you mean that you are able to send email with some other scripts but not with this script ? If you are unable to send email from any scripts please check your SMTP server if it allows message relaying.

Comment: yes exactly, but although its a good script, i wants to use it